# Analyse de la phrase : «Tu peux lui dire de venir me voir.»

Tags: grammaire, syntaxe

Je ne sais pas comment analyser la phrase suivante :

> Tu peux lui dire de venir me voir.

Je dirais que *tu* est le sujet, *peux dire* est le verbe, *lui* est le COI, et *de venir me voir* est le COD mais ça me semble douteux.

L'autre possibilité pourrait être que *tu* est le sujet, *peux* est le verbe copule, *lui* est le COI, *dire* est le complément du verbe *peux*, et *de venir me voir* est le COD.

Est-ce que l'une de ces possibilités est correcte ? 
De plus, est-ce qu'il faut analyser *de venir me voir* plus précisément ou est-ce qu'on peut le laisser comme ça ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On va commencer par une constante dans tes deux analyses :

*"Tu est le sujet"*. Oui! Forcément! Seul un verbe conjugué a un sujet (au sens grammatical), *pouvoir* est le seul verbe conjugué => *Tu* est le sujet... sujet **du verbe** pouvoir. (graissé car... attention, cela est souvent sous-entendu mais... en grammaire... on n'est jamais sujet absolument... on l'est... d'un verbe et cela aura son importance par la suite...

Tout comme... un COD ou un COI... d'ailleurs. ;)

La suite se complique un peu du fait que (et tu l'as bien senti avec ton hésitation sur la fonction copule) le verbe est *pouvoir*...

Avec tout autre verbe, prenons *aimer* par ex. *Tu aimerais lui dire*, [lui dire] serait tout bonnement un groupe verbal infinitif complément direct. (ta suggestion 1) Point!

Le problème avec *pouvoir* est que (tout comme c'est le cas avec *aller, faillir, manquer, laisser, devoir*) ce verbe fait souvent fonction de *semi-auxiliaire*. (Je suppose que c'est ce que tu entendais par *fonction copule*)
Dans ce cas, on ne parle effectivement plus, pour ce qui suit, de GV inf CD puisqu'à ce moment le GV c'est bien [SA+infinitif]. (~ta suggestion 2)

Mais je ne crois pas que ce soit le cas dans ton exemple. *pouvoir* (ainsi que les autres de la liste ci-dessus) ne peuvent être tenus pour semi-auxiliaires **que si ils perdent leur sens propre** pour exprimer des nuances de modalité.
Or, dans ton exemple, j'entends pour ma part le verbe *pouvoir* utilisé dans son sens propre de capacité. Dans ce contexte, j'entends *tu peux* comme, *tu as /je te donne - le pouvoir de...*

*Pouvoir* en son sens propre donc (selon ma compréhension) => [lui dire] = GV inf CD.

Quant à la suite... il s'agit juste... d'une précision... d'un détail... d'un... complément d'information => [venir me voir] est une **complétive**.
Dans le détail, on la dira *complétive infinitive objet direct*... **du GV inf** (v.g. pas de *pouvoir*) et dont on pourrait, au demeurant, faire une authentique proposition subordonnée en paraphrasant : *qu'il vienne me voir*.

En résumé donc et, selon ma compréhension de cette phrase :

- Tu : sujet du verbe pouvoir,
- lui dire : Groupe verbal infinitif complément direct du verbe pouvoir,
- de venir me voir : Complétive infinitive complément direct du groupe verbal [lui dire]

Nota : Dans l'analyse d'une phrase, tout commence avec les verbes. Isoler les groupes verbaux. Et ici, à cause de l'ambigüité de statut du verbe *pouvoir*, tout tourne autour de la question de **décider** si [*pouvoir dire*] est le groupe verbal ou si *pouvoir* est le verbe et *dire* un GV Inf CD. Ci dessus, j'ai décidé pour ma part... tu es bien évidemment libre d'en décider autrement.
Ce qui fait qu'à mon jugement tes deux analyses sont justes (d'où mon +1 sur ta question)... à la condition **impérative**... d'à chaque fois préciser... sujet, COD, COI... **de quoi**. ;-)

Comment: Désolée pour cette réponse tardive et merci beaucoup pour vos explications. Je n'ai pas connu les termes comme "groupe verbale infinitif", "complétive infinitive", etc. A propos, est-ce que vous pouvez me recommander des resources en ligne qui s'occupent de l'analyse de phrases ? J'ai vu quelque chose sur françaisfacile mais j'ai besoin de quelque chose de plus avancé.

Comment: @lmc : Ton aisance est notable mais le français ne me semble pas être ta langue maternelle. Auquel cas, je peux te recommander : Le point du FLE (Français Langue Étrangère) qui comprend des cours et des exos : https://www.lepointdufle.net/p/grammaire.htm Mais, étant donné ton niveau, je te recommanderai aussi de suivre et participer à des forums tels que http://www.languefrancaise.net/forum/ sur lesquels tu trouveras ample matière sans compter l'assistance d'authentiques spécialistes.

Comment: C'est vrai que le français n'est pas ma langue maternelle. Merci beaucoup, je vais voir ça.